# Migrate hibernate 3 to hibernate 5. alternate way of getHibernateTemplate() and HibernateCallback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The following code is developed by hibernate 3. i want to migrate this to hibernate 5. getHibernateTemplate() and HibernateCallback is show error how to fix this error.

```
public List<Employee> getAllSalaryPersons () {
    List<Employee> empSalList= super.getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List<Employee>>(){
        public List<Employee> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException  {

            Criteria criteria  = session.createCriteria(Salary.class, "sclass")
                    .createAlias("salary", "salary")
                    .add(Restrictions.le("sclass.salary", 25000))
                    .add(Restrictions.gt("sclass.salary", 99000))
                    .setProjection(
                            Projections.projectionList().addOrder( Order.asc("sclass.experiance") );

            criteria.setResultTransformer( new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Employee.class));

            return criteria.list();
        }
    });
    return empSalList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `HibernateTemplate` entirely (whose package name changes with each major Hibernate version) and instead use `SessionFactory`.

That way, you won't have to change the code again when you eventually upgrade to Hibernate 6 or 7...

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<Employee> getAllSalaryPersons () {
    Criteria criteria  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Salary.class, "sclass")
            .createAlias("salary", "salary")
            .add(Restrictions.le("sclass.salary", 25000))
            .add(Restrictions.gt("sclass.salary", 99000))
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList())
            .addOrder(Order.asc("sclass.experiance")) ;
    criteria.setResultTransformer( new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Employee.class));
    return criteria.list();        
}
```

Comment: if any possible way to do without annotation?

Comment: ...you could use a setter or constructor instead of autowiring in your `SessionFactory`. I just prefer to leverage Spring's dependency injection since it's available